What are the chances of me getting a high number?
So at my job there are 20 nurses. For a holiday draw (we get to sign up for the holidays we want to work in whatever number we draw) they write 1-20 on pieces of paper and we draw a number in the order we were hired. I am 19th to draw. Do my odds of getting top ten lessen since I’m almost last to draw or is it an even chance all the way down to 20?

Does this answer your question ?
